# AS3 creating new instances from blueprints

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I'm learning how classes work, it's pretty complicated. I need an example of a right object creation. Let's say I have a MovieClip blueprint in my library. It can be used as an example to create many instances with names that can further be used as objects in code to change their properties. So pretend I have a blueprint "AppleBP". I set it as Apple class (assume, it creates a file Apple.as?). I need a code that would create (by pushing a button, for example) an instance Apple01 that would appear at a random place on the screen (just to know it's different from others, I know how to randomize position). Then make Apple02, Apple03, Apple04 and Apple05. If it's hard to set name to "Apple" + N, it's ok to stick to an array with names or at least pick it like if(N = 1){//code for Apple01 creation} then N++ etc.

So for now I tried

```
var Apple01:Apple = new Apple();
Apple01.visible = true; //just in case I can't see it
Apple01.x = 100;
Apple01.y = 100;
TextField01.text = "blahblah"; //to see if code actually works
```

Apple doesn't appear, text does. So what am I missing if creating a new class that is a MovieClip blueprint isn't enough? And how would I pick new names for each new instance so that it had variable String instead of pure name? (so that I could change the name as text + number based on it's order)

Add:

```
package  {
import flash.display.Scene;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

public class MyFirstClass extends MovieClip{ 

        //var N:int;
        var n:int;
        var existingApples:int = 0;
        var apples:Array = new Array();     

    public function MyFirstClass():void{
        MakeNewApple();
        MakeNewApple();
        MakeNewApple();
        MakeNewApple();
        MakeNewApple();

        //apple4.x = 5;
        //apple4.y = 5;

        var draggableApple:Apple = apples[0] ;
        draggableApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draggableApple.onMouseDown) ;
        draggableApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, draggableApple.onMouseUp) ;
        info01.text = "Did it";
    }
    public function MakeNewApple():void{
        if(existingApples < 5){
        n = existingApples;
        var apple:Apple = new Apple();
        stage.addChild(apple);
        apple.x = (Math.random()*600+100);
        apple.y = (Math.random()*400+100);
        apple.name = "apple" + n;

        apples.push(apple.name);
        existingApples++;
        trace(existingApples);
        trace(apples);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Apple.as:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

public class Apple extends MovieClip{

    public function Apple() {

    }

    public function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
        this.startDrag();
    }
    public function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void{
        this.stopDrag();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to do addChild(Apple01) for it to show up. So first you create an instance by doing new Apple(), then you add it to the display list (the objects on stage) using addChild(Apple01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is come commented example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Scene;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void {   

            var apples:Array = new Array() ; // Declare and array
            for (var i:int = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) { //Let's make 10 apples
                var apple:Apple = new Apple() ; //Create an apple
                apple.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth)  ; //Assign random x
                apple.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) ; //Assign random y
                stage.addChild(apple) ; //Add it to stage, so we can see them
                apples.push(apple) ; //Push into array
            }
            //EDITED
            var draggableApple:Apple = apples[0] ;
            draggableApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draggableApple.onMouseDown) ;
            draggableApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, draggableApple.onMouseUp) ;

        }

    }

}
```

And Apple.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Apple extends MovieClip {

    public function Apple() {
        this.graphics.lineStyle(2) ;
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF40) ;
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20) ;
        this.graphics.endFill() ;

        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown) ;
        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp) ;
    }

    public function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
        this.startDrag() ;
    }

    public function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
        this.stopDrag() ;
    }
}
}
```

- Also, name of all variables must start with a small letter. myVariable
- Names of classes must implement CamelCaseClass
- Names of constants contain only big letters and underscores. MY_CONSTANT

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed addChild then. So how about the rest? You draw a Sprite and I have an existing blueprint(symbol) type MovieClip AppleBP, which I set class Apple. It's empty for now. My apple appears but I cant apply stuff to it, can't drag it for example. It just says "apple" is unidentified even though I just created it. And, well, it's weird cause I have just set apple.x and apple.y, but it wont see apple.addEventListener and his function.

Comment: Also about names. So how do I make it use 10 different names and apply functions to any of them? Like applying addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,drag01) to any Apple class instance on the stage?

Comment: @SherWood Updated some code. Made only first apple (apples[0]) draggable. That's how you access elements from array and perform needed actions. Hope it helped you.

Comment: Umm, you know, it still hates me. Says apples in the addEventListener line is undefined property... And it says the same if I attempt to create array inside the function so I have to make array in the class body. Does yours work?

Comment: What IDE do you use? I use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/). All code was compiled fine and I see all results. 1 circle out of 10 I can drag.

Comment: Added the code. Sorry, I know it's a pain to read someone else's code... I just want to understand why doesn't it work, what am I missing. Maybe I didn't connect the Classes properly? Maybe didn't import something? (it's why I used *) It says something about inability to call functions onMouseDown and Up and says can't make apple0 an Apple. Same about when I'm trying to change apple4 position to see if I actually do have 5 objects in my stage that I can work with. I can't =( Trace says I have 5 objects named apple0-apple4. What do you think?

Comment: Write your code on [piratepad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/) and paste me the link, I'll have a look at it :)